# How to parallelize a for loop in C++ creating the thread pool only once

Tags: c++, windows, multithreading

I have a C++ program that must run in Windows.

I have a game that has a main loop in the function `WinMain` which calls the `Update` functions in each iteration. I want to apply multithreading to a loop of update functions.

```cpp
int __stdcall WinMain()
{
    // Windows initializations

    // Main loop
    {
        Game game = new Game();
        bool bExit = false;
        while (!bExit)
        {
            MSG msg;
            while (PeekMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0, PM_REMOVE))
            {
                if (msg.message == WM_QUIT) bExit = true;
                TranslateMessage(&msg);
                DispatchMessage(&msg);
            }

            game->Update();
        }
        delete game;
        game = nullptr;
    }

    // Windows destructions

    return 0;
}
```

```cpp
// Game.cpp

void Game::Update() {
    // Loop that I want to be parallelized but I don't want to create the thread pool here because it's called on every frame
    for (size_t i = 0; i < entities.size(); i++) {
        entities[i]->Update();
    }
}
```

I tried using OpenMP but I couldn't place the `#pragma omp parallel` in the `WinMain` function (the app would crash) and if I put `#pragma omp parallel for` inside the `Game::Update` just before the loop it actually decreases performance because it's creating the thread loop in each frame.

I'm looking for a library-based or preferably a native solution that allows me to easily parallelize this loop.

The only requirements is that it works in Windows, I would prefer not using a library (like boost, although OpenMP is fine).

EDIT: I got it working with PPL's `concurrency::parallel_for`. It doesn't degrade performance but it doesn't increase it either... My question regarding this is: does this function create and destroy its thread pool on each call?

Comment: Have you looked at the native Windows thread pool?

Comment: @ZuodianHu An abstraction for the thread management is preferred since I'm not experienced with Windows thread API and I need to do this project today.

Comment: I know you said boost is not preferred, but it has a really simple header-only thread pool in Boost.Asio. Boost.Asio also lets you write your own pool easily using an io_context. Other than that I don't know of any quick non-library solutions that doesn't require you to write your own thread-safe queue

Comment: @ZuodianHu It's just because Boost requires installation and learning the library. If you could elaborate a simple example then I'd probably try it.

Comment: @ZuodianHu Thank you for the example. I tried a simple `concurrency::parallel_for` and it worked. However I still don't know where the thread pool is created for it.

Comment: I'm actually unfamiliar with that library. However, a bit of reading seems to indicate the thread pool is completely hidden from you when you use `concurrency::parallel_for`

Comment: Are you sure you need to parallelize your game? If you have lag issues, you might instead just need a fixed-timestep game loop. Google "*windows framerate-independent game loop*". And read this: https://gafferongames.com/post/fix_your_timestep/

Answer (score 1):

Providing a Boost.Asio example based on our discussion in the comments:

```cpp
#include <thread>

#include <boost/asio.hpp>

namespace asio = boost::asio;

int main( int argc, int* argv[] ) {
    asio::io_context context{};

    asio::post( context, []() { /* any arbitrary job */ } );

    // this donates the new_thread to the thread pool
    std::thread new_thread{ [&](){ context.run(); } };

    // this donates the current thread to the thread pool
    context.run();
}
```

The main things to note here are:

1. `asio::post` allows you to submit arbitrary jobs to the `io_context`
2. calling `io_context::run` from a thread donates that thread to the thread pool that runs the context

If you want a pre-built thread pool, you can use a `boost::asio::thread_pool`, and call `asio::post` to put jobs on the thread pool in the same way.

You should only need to download Boost, you shouldn't need to install it. If you add `BOOST_ERROR_CODE_HEADER_ONLY` to you compilation, Boost.Asio is totally header-only.

EDIT:

You still need to run Boost's setup script, but you shouldn't need to build any of the libraries.

Answer (score 1):

Here a solution with basic thread library. I simulated your `Entity` and `Game` classes.
Note that in this solution, worker thread are created and started ONE time at the beginning. They will be called on each `Update` call. When `Update` is not called, threads sleeps ...

I did my best to keep the architecture of your program.
Note that we can use another implementation with std::thread, std::mutex, ... but I just wanted to give you an idea ...

```
#define NB_ENTITIES 10

class CEntity
{
public:
    void Update(){};
    ~CEntity () {}
};

typedef struct ThreadData
{
    HANDLE  hMutex;
    HANDLE  hMutexDestructor;
    CEntity *pCEntity;  
    DWORD   *dwStat;

} ThreadData;

//------------------------------------
// This function will call "Upadate"
//------------------------------------
DWORD WINAPI MyThreadFunction( LPVOID lpParam )
{
    ThreadData *ThreadDatpa      = (ThreadData*) lpParam;
    CEntity    *pEntity          = ThreadDatpa->pCEntity;
    HANDLE     hMutex            = ThreadDatpa->hMutex;
    HANDLE     hMutexDestructor  = ThreadDatpa->hMutexDestructor;
    DWORD      *dwStat           = ThreadDatpa->dwStat;

    while (true)
    {
        // When no update, thread sleep ... 0% CPU ...
        WaitForSingleObject(hMutex, INFINITE);
        if ( 0 == *dwStat ) break; // here thread stat for stopping 

        if ( nullptr != pEntity ) 
            pEntity->Update(); // Call your unpdate function ...
    }

    // Each worker thread must release it semaphore.
    // Destructor must get ALL released semaphore before deleting memory
    ReleaseSemaphore(hMutexDestructor, 1, NULL );

    return 0;
}

class Game 
{
public :
    vector<ThreadData*>  entities; // Vector of entities pointers
    vector<HANDLE>   thread_group; // vector of threads handle


    //This function must called ONE time at the beginning (at init)
    void StartThreads ()
    {
        DWORD  dwRet = 0;
        HANDLE hTemp = NULL;

        for (size_t i = 0; i <NB_ENTITIES; i++) 
        {
            CEntity *pCEntity = new CEntity (); // just to simulate entity

            // This semaphore is used to release thread when update is called
            HANDLE ghMutex= CreateSemaphore( NULL,0, 1, NULL); 

            // This semaphore is used when destruction to check if all threads is terminated
            HANDLE ghMutexDestructor= CreateSemaphore( NULL,0, 1, NULL);

            // create a new CEntity data ...
            ThreadData *pThreadData = new ThreadData ();

            pThreadData->pCEntity = pCEntity;
            pThreadData->hMutex   = ghMutex;
            pThreadData->hMutexDestructor = ghMutexDestructor;
            pThreadData->dwStat   = new DWORD (1); // default status = 1 

            entities.push_back ( pThreadData );         
        }

        // Here we start ONE time Threads worker.
        // Threads are stopped untile update was called
        for (size_t i = 0; i < entities.size(); i++) 
        {
            // Each thread has it own entity
            hTemp = CreateThread( NULL,0, MyThreadFunction, entities.at(i), 0, &dwRet);  
            if ( NULL != hTemp )
                thread_group.push_back (hTemp);
        }

    }

    // Your function update juste wakeup threads
    void Game::Update() {
        for (size_t i = 0; i < entities.size(); i++) 
        {
            HANDLE hMutex = entities.at(i)->hMutex;
            if ( NULL != hMutex )
                ReleaseSemaphore(hMutex, 1, NULL );
        }
    }


    ~Game()
    {
        // Modifie stat before releasing threads
        for (size_t i = 0; i < entities.size(); i++) 
            *(entities.at(i)->dwStat) = 0;

        // Release threads (status =0 so break ...)
        Update();

        // This can be replaced by waitformultipleobjects ...
        for (size_t i = 0; i < entities.size(); i++)
            WaitForSingleObject ( entities.at(i)->hMutexDestructor, INFINITE);

        // Now i'm sur that all threads are terminated
        for (size_t i = 0; i < entities.size(); i++)
        {
            delete entities.at(i)->pCEntity;
            delete entities.at(i)->dwStat;
            CloseHandle (entities.at(i)->hMutex);
            CloseHandle (entities.at(i)->hMutexDestructor);
            delete entities.at(i);
        }

    }
};
```